# Can a new Cycle only be started at the end

Tags: disgaea

in a save file i have i am on the 2nd cycle, i want to start the cycle all over again as there is an ally death in it, in my old save i was close to the end with no ally deaths and have some powered up equipment with level 300 Managers and Statisticians, this got wiped out when most of my games in my memory stick got corrupted for some reason

i am wondering if i can restart this from the start or if i have to beat the game before i can do that

Comment: If I remember right you can intentionally lose to the midboss and then do a new game plus, at least for the DS version

Comment: @spartacus which encounter with Mid Boss (or rather whihc chapter), i'm hoping it's after Chapter 3 cause the save i have downloaded is on that chapter

Comment: any of them should suffice

Comment: @spartacus he showed up in Chapter 4 though i had to create a bunch of Prinnys to get the 10 deaths on the map, worked fine, could you put down your response as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Disgaea 3 was the first to allow starting new game plus at any point after finishing the story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you lose to the midboss (at any of the fights where he shows up), you will get a scenic ending and that will allow you to start a new game plus.